# AndroidImageSlider: createBitmap error and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android

Sorry for my English.
In its application, I use Android Image Slider https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

here's the code:

```
 SliderLayout exPhoto = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.ex_img);
 exPhoto.removeAllSliders();
 for (String url : object.getImages()) {
 try {
 Log.e("test", "load textSliderView");
 TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
 textSliderView
      .image(url)
      .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
 exPhoto.addSlider(textSliderView);
 }catch (OutOfMemoryError e){
 Log.e("test", "exception textSliderView");
 }
 }
 exPhoto.stopAutoCycle();
```

here's error:

```
05-11 15:41:08.855 5873-6125/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/Bitmap? createBitmap error!
05-11 15:41:09.335 5873-6126/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1674K, 18% free 53549K/64995K, paused 4ms+22ms
05-11 15:41:09.445 5873-5873/ru.mabee.justme_android.app E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:492)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:360)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:542)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:315)
at com.squareup.picasso.ImageViewAction.error(ImageViewAction.java:61)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.deliverAction(Picasso.java:563)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.complete(Picasso.java:510)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$1.handleMessage(Picasso.java:117)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/dalvikvm? GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 395K, 17% free 54464K/64995K, paused 2ms+18ms
E/dalvikvm? GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 105K, 17% free 54358K/64995K, paused 170ms
E/dalvikvm-heap? Out of memory on a 983056-byte allocation.
```

All I can do is to pass the path to the image

```
 textSliderView
      .image(url)
      .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
```

I do not work directly with Bitmaps

This error occurs on the low phone and after 20 updates.

please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you should do exPhoto.stopAutoCycle(); in onStop of your activity or in onDestroyView of fragment, not right after creating views, this described in example of your lib

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // To prevent a memory leak on rotation, make sure to call stopAutoCycle() on the slider before activity or fragment is destroyed
    mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
    super.onStop();
}
```

if this will not help, try to figure out if you have memory leaks somewhere else